# Silverlight and the speech sdk

Tags: silverlight, sdk, speech

I would like to have Silverlight read text.  I've seen this done with the speech SDK, does anyone know if Silverlight supports that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two links I discovered on the Silverlight forums suggest Silverlight doesn't directly support the Speech SDK. The suggested solution is to create an ActiveX Object that does the TTS (using the Speech SDK), and have Silverlight interact with that ActiveX Object.

http://silverlight.net/forums/t/5650.aspx
http://silverlight.net/forums/t/51571.aspx

It looks like Microsoft may have an ActiveX Object which does this already. I'm not too familiar with ActiveX programming, but it looks like the Speech SDK contains an ActiveX COM object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997568.aspx